# How To Dynamically Add or Remove Dropdown List?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I am trying to dynamically create dropdown list inside my form and return the selected values of all the dropdown list and other form control back to my controller.

The minimum number of dropdown list is 1 and maximum number of dropdown list that can be exist is the number of options in the dropdown list. For example, if the number of options is 5, the number of downdrop list can range from 1 to 5.

**Dropdown list options**

```
public enum Subject: byte
{
   English = 0,
   Mathematics,
   Biology,
   Physics,
   Chemistry,
   Geography,
   History
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Student
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "Name")]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "D.O.B")]
   public string DOB { get; set; }

    public string SelectedSubject { get; set; }

   //I want to create dynamic drop down lists for subjects
   //TODO: add supporting properties to get selected subjects
}
```

**View**

```
...
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        <div class="form-group>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB)
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB)
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSubject, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Subject))))
            </div>
        </div>
        @*Add "Add subject" button"*@
        @*Add dropdown list, Add "Remove" button and shift Add button to the back*@
        @*the newly added dropdown list is just beside the previous one*@
        @*Number of dropdown list: 1 to 7*@
        @*If number of dropdown list is 7, add button is hidden*@
        @*If number of dropdown list is 1, delete button is hidden*@
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value=Create />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
//TODO: add more parameters to support getting the data from the dropdownlist
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Student student, **add other parameter to support dropdown list selected value**)
{
    ...
}
```

All the commented are areas I am not sure what to add.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying. So you have a fixed number of enum list, and basically you just want users to select multiple from it (because you said the users have to select at least 1, and at most 7, all of them)? It's not like you want to dynamically add/remove options to/from that enum list is it?

Comment: Multiselect dropdown list can also fulfill what I want to do. I didn't though of that. Thanks.